# Running in app mode + download in same tab

Tags: google-chrome

I'm running chromium in app mode to prevent my users from interacting with the URL bar (the usage is for a very specific app and we don't want them to go where they want)

My problem is when a download is initiated, it opens a new window to deal with the download, and this window is not in app mode, so my users can do what they want with the browser

I want to allow downloads, but to prevent getting out of the app mode, or at least, open a new window, but also in app mode

Thanks

Comment: app mode is running with the flag --app=http://facebook.com

Comment: I see, in that case it's not related to [google-chrome-app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), and the only solution is probably to [disable the download prompt via policies](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=PromptForDownloadLocation).

Comment: I've just tried it, still opens a new window, that is not in app mode

Comment: Show a screenshot of that new window and describe how you initiate the download.

Comment: Did you tried this `<a href="your-data-uri" download="filename.txt">`

Comment: This is the download : `<a id="exportetherpada" target="_blank" class="exportlink" href="/etherpad/p/test123test/export/etherpad"></a>`

Comment: I know the _blank is working as it should, but removing it makes a 403 error ...